# Get text in href using Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
    import csv
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    # create initial CSV file
    with open('mycsvfile.csv','w') as f:
         f.write('Period,Short_Desc,Temp\n') # TRAILING NEWLINE

    # Call Website to get data
    page = requests.get("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=37.7772&lon=-122.4168")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    location = soup.find(id="fcst-search")
    location_items = location.find_all(id="getfcst-headOffice")
    location_name = location_items[0]    

    # stuck here? confused...
    location_site = location_name.find(class_="period-name").get_text()

    print(location_name.prettify())
```

if you look at the link, I am trying to get the name of the city and then later in my working code i output to a csv.  how do i get the name of city in the href  tag? thanks.

```
    <div id="getfcst-head">
        <p>Your local forecast office is</p>
            <h3 id="getfcst-headOffice"><a href="http://www.wrh.noaa.gov/sew">Seattle, WA</a></h3>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML doesn't show up with the link in the source... at least not visible through BeautifulSoup. That "local forecast office" is being pulled from somewhere else dynamically. You can pull it from another location on the page though...

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# create initial CSV file
with open('mycsvfile.csv','w') as f:
     f.write('Period,Short_Desc,Temp\n') # TRAILING NEWLINE

# Call Website to get data
page = requests.get("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=37.7772&lon=-122.4168")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

location_header = soup.find('a', id="localWFO").get('title')
print location_header
```

Results in:

```
San Francisco Bay Area/Monterey, CA
```

Comment: print (location_header) is correct syntax on my windows machine. 
Thank you for your answer, it works.